# Append JSON in Body request in Jmeter

Tags: json, jsr223

My Http Body request:

```
{
  "FormTemplate": "[{\"_reference\":\"ID.ParentId1\",\"MetadataId\":111,\"fieldLabel\":\"ClientLable\"}]",
  "Type": 1,
  "Fields": [
        {
            "MetadataFieldId": 381,
            "DisplayName": "Parent Client",
            "DefaultValue": null,      
        }
    ],
    "Settings": [],
    "DateUpdated": "2017-07-01T08:49:11.433Z"
}
```

I wants to append the values some random values in FormTemplate like -

> "[{\"_reference\":\"ID.ParentId1\",\"MetadataId\":111,\"fieldLabel\":\"ClientLable\"},{\"_reference\":\"ID.ParentId2\",\"MetadataId\":222,\"fieldLabel\":\"ClientLable\"}]"

I know that this can be achieved by JSR223 PostProcessor But I am new to jmeter and Don't know JSR223 PostProcessor scripting. So I am looking for IDE in which I can make sample script and debug it or have the ready code to append the value.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, Through User Define Variable I just append this string in body part which give me the desired out put.